# How would I write the SQL to show Email_To data that goes to an individual?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data that looks similar to this:

| TaskID | Email_To |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | @Email.org.uk; |
| 2 | @Email.org.uk; @Email.org.uk; |
| 3 | @Email.org.uk |

In the Email_To column, there can be multiple individuals that certain tasks email to. The individuals are split up by the ";". However, there is inconsistent use of the semicolon. Some tasks with only one email_to use the semicolon and some do not.
Would there be a way to identify only those tasks that email to individuals?

Comment: Look for rows that don't contain a semicolon (`;`)?

Comment: @Larnu, sample data look like semicolon is mandatory at the end of a list

Comment: Didn't notice that, thanks @Serg .

Comment: The semicolon use is inconsistent. Some tasks to individuals have a semicolon and some do not.

Comment: That should really be apparent in your sample data, @EmirAshraf . 2 examples, both with a semicolon at the end, suggests that the character is *always* there.

Comment: I have edited the post now. This is my first post so I am new to this.

Comment: you could check for a single @.. `where Email_To like '%@%'
and Email_To not like '%@%@%'`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the first semicolon is the last char in a string or missing at all

```
select *
from tbl
where where charindex(';', Email_To) in (0, len(Email_To));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always (or could) have a semicolon (`;`) at the end, you could `TRIM` those first, and then check if the character is in the string. This *assumes* you are using a fully supported version of SQL Server, due to the omission of contrary information:

```sql
SELECT Task_ID,
       Email_To
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE TRIM(';' FROM Email_To) LIKE '%;%';
```

Comment: Probably best to trim spaces also `TRIM('; ' FROM...`

Comment: Quite possibly, @Charlieface , considering that the data has inconsistent use of terminators/separators.

Comment: Hi @Larnu Can you please tell me what is the difference between `TRIM(';' FROM Email_To)`  and `TRIM(Email_To) `. How this `FROM Email_To` will be used in this context?

Comment: [TRIM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) @Bhushan .

Comment: I know TRIM. But I am curious to know how FROM Clause is used in this WHERE condition here. If you don't mind any such examples

Comment: Then you already know what `';' FROM` does, @Bhushan . Did you look at the examples in the linked documentation, which details *what* it does? What about those examples didn't you understand and I can try to elaborate.

Comment: Actually I am not able to understand what `';' FROM` does

Comment: It *"Remove(s) specified characters from both sides of string"* @Bhushan . `;` is the specified character(s). It's all there in the documentation, hence why I asked what you didn't understand.